# group by a dataframe by the max column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have this dataframe and I need to leave only the lines with the max value of the 'revisão' column referring to each value of the 'mesano' column
[image: dataframe]

`groupede=dfgc.groupby(['mesano','description','paymentCategories.description','paymentCategories.type']) result=groupede['revisao','paymentCategories.interval.totalPrice'].agg('max','sum')`

and i try too

grouped=dfgc.groupby(['mesano','description','paymentCategories.description','paymentCategories.type','paymentCategories.interval.totalPrice'], as_index=False)['revisao'].max()

but this code is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the dataframe by highest value in revisao and then drop all duplicate rows and only keep the first entry, essentially filtering by max value:

```
df.sort_values(by=['revisão'], ascending=False).drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```

Comment: I got it this way:
`  df=dfgc.groupby(['mesano','description','paymentCategories.description'])['revisao'].max().reset_index()  `

'pd.merge(df,dfgc,how='left',on=['mesano','description','paymentCategories.description','revisao'])'

Answer (score 0):

We can choose only the rows for which the value of a particular column is equal to the maximum value for that column. This can be done by using Boolean index filtering, where a 1 in the boolean index specifies keeping this row, and 0 means dropping it. For your particular use case, you can use

```
df_max_revisão = df[df['revisão'] == df['revisão'].max()]
```

where df['revisão'] == df['revisão'].max() generates a boolean index, and df[boolean_index] gives you the rows with 1 in the boolean index.
If you want only the values in the 'mesano' column, you can filter the dataset and choose those by using

```
df_mesano = df['mesano']
```

Comment: I got it this way: ` df=dfgc.groupby(['mesano','description','paymentCategories.description'])['revisao'].max().reset_index() ` 'pd.merge(df,dfgc,how='left',on=['mesano','description','paymentCategories.description','revisao'])